# How to embed html link in a String Android?

Tags: android, html, href

Hi I know how to embed a html in a string in xml.

```
<string name="our_policy">Our app 
    <a href="www.google.com">Policy</a> and 
    <a href="www.google.com">Terms</a>
</string>
```

But I have to add some more things into this during run time.How to embed html link in a string during run time and sent it via Intent to gmail.Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<a href=http://www.google.com >Google</a>"));
```

It is the better way.

Comment: On top of that you could extract "http://www.google.com"  in a res file or as static member